# opencart get all downloadable files

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I trying to get and display all downloadable files in product page. here is my code:

**model:**

```
public function download_m($product_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    if ($query->num_rows) {
      return array(
        'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],        
        'download_id'      => $query->row['download_id']
      );
    } 
}
```

**controller:**

```
$download_m = $this->model_catalog_product->download_m($product_id);
```

**view:**

```
print_r($download_m)
```

**database:**

[image]

as you see there are two downloadable items with product_id **95**, but it just return `3` not `3,4`. what did i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code to get result as you want

```
$return_result=array();
if ($query->num_rows) {
  foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $return_result[]=array(
      'product_id'       => $result['product_id'],        
      'download_id'      => $result['download_id']
    );
 }
} 
return $return_result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loop for each results like this.

```
if ($query->num_rows) {
    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
        return array(
          'product_id'       => $result['product_id'],        
          'download_id'      => $result['download_id']
        );
     }
}
```

You can check this type of code everywhere in Opencart files.

Comment: it return `Array ( [product_id] => 95 [download_id] => 3 )`
`

Comment: Because you returning array of single index